# How to sort by nested data in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, sequelize.js

I need to implement the ability to sort records in the Comments table both by its own fields and by the fields of the nested table. For example, you can sort records by date added, but you also need to be able to sort by a field in a nested table, such as username or email. I'm trying to do this, but sorting only works by the main table.

```
async getListComments(data) {
    try {
      const { limit, offset, sortBy, sortOrder } = data
      const list = await Comments.findAndCountAll({
        where: { parentId: null },
        include: 'User',
        limit: limit || 25,
        offset: offset * limit || 0,
        order: [
          [sortBy || 'id', sortOrder || 'ASC'],
          ['User', sortBy || 'id', sortOrder || 'ASC'],
        ],
      })
      return list
    } catch (e) {
      throw createHttpError(500, e)
    }
  }
```

Example output of a comment object

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "text": "gi",
            "parentId": null,
            "createdAt": "2023-10-28T15:02:19.246Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-10-28T15:02:19.246Z",
            "UserId": 1,
            "User": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "testffкgggggg",
                "email": "testttggggggк@gmail.com",
                "avatar": "avatars/16985052434303eQcywnQksHcl08Mct3BC6Ud.jpg",
                "createdAt": "2023-10-28T15:00:43.472Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-10-28T15:00:43.472Z"
            }
        },
```

Also an request example

```
localhost:4000/api/comments/list?sortBy=id&sortOrder=ASC
```

Comment: Try something like `[\`User.${sortBy || 'id'}\`, sortOrder || 'ASC']`

Comment: @Titus ok, but how to sort by fieds in Comments model, for example createdAt in this way

Comment: The first array `[sortBy || 'id', sortOrder || 'ASC']` should do that.

Comment: @Titus I'm trying your code? but it doesn't work I got an exception ```  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')```

Comment: The error that you're getting is not evident from the code that you've provided.
You're probably using something like `someVariableName.type` and `someVariableName` is `undefined`.

Comment: If `id` is PK of `Comments` how do you expect to sort records by a unique field and then by some other field? The records all always be in the same order by ascending `id` values.